# How to generate every possible configuration of a small square lattice with entries +1 and -1?(Ising Model)

Tags: python, lattice, montecarlo

I'm currently running a Markov Chain Monte Carlo Ising Model simulation using the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm. In order to make sure my simulation is running properly, I'm looking to compute the exact expression of the partition function so as the obtain the true equilibrium distribution, then compare the sampled frequencies of my lattice(plotted as a histogram) from simulation and compare it against the true distribution.

**I know this is quite computationally heavy to run for large lattices**, hence I only want to do it for lattice with small dimensions. In order to compute the partition function which shows the true distribution

`Z = np.exp(-beta*energy_i)/sum(np.exp(-beta*energy_n))`

For a `2x2` lattice, there are `2^4=16` lattice configurations, for every configuration `i` its energy is calculated by this function. Here `i = 1, 2,..., 16`, and the denominator of the `Z` is the sum of all the exponential terms of the configurations. `Beta` is the inverse temperature but if you just leave it then I'll sort it out myself.

```
def calcEnergy(config):
    '''Energy of a given configuration'''
    energy = 0
    for i in range(len(config)):
        for j in range(len(config)):
            S = config[i, j]
            nb = config[(i+1) % N, j] + config[i, (j+1) % N] + \
                config[(i-1) % N, j] + config[i, (j-1) % N]
            energy += -nb*S
    return energy/4.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the description of problem, but answering to the question in the topic:

Just go loop from 0 to n where n is number of possible configurations and for each "i" in the loop take it's binary representation assuming 1 is 1 and 0 is -1

Comment: Assuming that you understood the problem, is there a way to do that in python? What I want is something like, assuming a 1x1 lattice, then the possible configurations there are really is just `np.array([[1]])` and `np.array([[-1]])`. So you can imagin for a 2x2 lattice, then the possible configurations are `np.array([[1,1],[1, 1]]), np.array([[1,1],[1, -1]]), np.array([[1,1],[-, 1]])...`etc up to 16 different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself in the end. For a lattice with dimension `LxL`.

```
def true_dist(L):
    perm = [list(seq) for seq in itertools.product("01", repeat=L*L)]
    perm = [[int(x) for x in value] for i, value in enumerate(perm)]
    perm = np.array(perm).reshape(2**(L*L), L, L)
    perm = np.where(perm==1, perm, -1)
    return perm
```

This function gives every possible configuration of `+1` and `-1`. Gets slower for bigger lattice, but does the job for me.